# How to force with iText7 a new blank page only when necessary in order to have each text exactly on two pages?

Tags: itext7

I'm using itext 7.2.1 and I've this situation: I have a list of letters with variable content that normally fits in one page, but occasionally can span over two pages.
My goal is to force a new blank page after the "short" letters so they start alway on odd pages. The length of text *is not know in advance*.

Basically I have the following code:

```
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("letters.pdf");
Document document = new Document(new PdfDocument(writer));
List<String> letters = . . .code to retrieve letters text;
int nLetter = 0;
for (String text : letters) {
  Paragraph p = new Paragraph().add(text);
  doc.add(p);
  nLetter++;
  //now after layout of last paragraph I must ensure that
  //the next paragraph starts on page (nLetter*2 + 1): how can I do this?
}
. . .
doc.close();
```

What is the best way to do so in iText7? I tried with custom DocumentRenderer but I haven't found a clean and working solution.

Comment: Can you give an example of desired input and ouput?

Answer (score 0):

The best and simpliest way to know if your next paragraph starts on the next page of the document is to get the root renderer of your document and get current area. And it will return the area(rectangle and page) where the end of the text is located.

```
doc.getRenderer().getCurrentArea();
```